# Why am I getting no-descending-specificity error?

Tags: sass, stylelint

Here's an example:

```
.something {
  & > * {
    &:not(:first-child) {
      margin-right: 16px;
    }
    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-left: 16px;
    }
  }
  &-element {
    & > * { /* Expected selector ".something-element > *" to come before selector ".something > *:not(:first-child)" (no-descending-specificity) */
      &:not(:first-child) {
        margin-top: 16px;
      }
      &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My stylelint.config.json:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['stylelint-config-recommended-scss'],
};
```

How can I fix stylelint error? Or maybe it's bug?

Comment: Compiles fine for me https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/062540ca6b2f326cb1b9bc2c55c6ce70

Comment: This has been flagged as a bug within stylelint https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/3738